# Not able to save session values in some controllers

Tags: laravel, lumen

Alright so this is an odd one.  I initially ran into some problems setting session values, but it turned out that it was because I wasn't `return`ing anything from the controller method that was setting the session value.

I resolved that and got my user controller to work, and it's been working just fine.

I'm setting like this in my `UserController`.  It seems like the docs reference a few different ways to interact with the session, but the `session()` method seems to be the more standard way - at least based on the lumen docs (http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/session).

```
session([
    'is_logged_in'  => true,
    'username'      => $user->getUsername(),
    'user'          => $user,
]);
```

And I'm doing my gets like so:

```
$user = session('user')
```

Now I'm trying to introduce some new functionality in a separate controller `AdminController`.  I want to set an additional variable in there:

```
session(['new_variable'  => 1])
```

But that session variable isn't actually saving to the session.

Now here's where it gets weird.  I'm doing this with the `cookie` driver currently.  If I change to the `file` driver then everything works completely as expected.

Also, with the `cookie` driver, if I set that variable from within the original `UserController` that's logging them in, as opposed to in the `AdminController`, then it also properly persists the session data.

But setting that session data from the `AdminController` using the `cookie` driver just doesn't work.

I thought perhaps this might have to do with the `path` setting on the cookie, but it seems that all of the cookie paths are set to '/' (as you would expect).  Also there isn't any different domain being used for this other controller - it's on the same domain.